# Why check if a $_GET variable is empty twice?

Tags: php, is-empty

Working with PHP some code and I came across some code that basically checks if the same variable is empty twice:

```
if ( !empty( $_GET[ 'branch' ] ) ) {
    $branch = $_GET[ 'branch' ];
}
if ( empty( $branch ) ) {
    _output( 'Error: no branch specified!' );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

Any idea why it's set up this way? What is the advantage over just using `else`, like this:

```
if ( !empty( $_GET[ 'branch' ] ) ) {
    $branch = $_GET[ 'branch' ];
} else {
    _output( 'Error: no branch specified!' );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

Comment: There is likely another way that branch gets set. The first if will set it to the `get` variable but i would wager there is another way it could get set too. then the final if would be there so that if neither way worked

Comment: @justinhoward: Or before those statements.

Comment: `empty()` checks for boolean emptyiness. Just because there was an input value present, doesn't mean it wasn't `"0"`.

Comment: @mario, that's probably the main motivation in this example. Mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) is more than just the inverse of [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset).

It tests for "non-falseness".
One could equate it with:

```
if (!isset($var) || $var == false)
```

Notably it checks with [dynamic type conversion](http://php.net/types.type-juggling). Which in your example probably makes sense, as things like the empty string, or `"0"`, or even `"0 sheep"` might not make useful branch names.

So it's often quite apt for form input, and explains the use after the `isset` check. Another common idiom is however `strlen()` or even `strlen(trim($var))` for testing present input text.

Comment: This was a URL parameter, so if someone does `&branch=0` or `&branch=false`, the script needed to take that into account.

Answer (score 7):

It isn't checking if the same variable is empty.  `$branch` isn't necessarily `$_GET['branch']` in this code and the first check is to check if `$_GET['branch']` **isn't** empty.

Throughout the code, there is most likely at least one other condition that `$branch` gets set.  This is most likely the last condition, therefore it is checking finally if `$branch` was set.  There might be better ways to resolve this but without seeing the entire code, I couldn't tell you.

---

Based on your comment below, this is the same thing and even more simple:

```
$branch = $_GET[ 'branch' ];
if ( empty( $branch ) ) {
    _output( 'Error: no branch specified!' );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

Why use an if at all on `$_GET['branch']` if `$branch` can only be `$_GET['branch']`?

Better yet you can use a ternary operator to just set a default branch and avoid the possibility of an error.

```
$branch = (empty($_GET['branch'])) ? DEFAULT_BRANCH : $_GET['branch'];
```

Comment: Well checking that it *isn't* empty is the same as checking that it *is* empty, just negated or placed in an `else` condition. The real question is, why check twice? Your answer is useful and probably correct for most people who find this on Google. I've done my part in upvoting. In my particular case, it was that it was a URL parameter and thus it made sense both to check if it existed at all and then double-check that the value wasn't something like `false` or `0`.

Comment: @brentonstrine If you only have one condition to set $branch then the second check is redundant because in that scenario, $branch will always be $_GET['branch'] or the script will fail.  I added in an edit about your comment.  There is no point to run an if else (or an if on $_GET['branch']) if there is only one way $branch can be set.

Answer (score 0):

Might exist another way that branch gets set and branch will get set later in the code. The first if checks if $_GET is not empty, btw.

There's no reason to do such checks in that way. Like this it looks a bit like code like this:

```
for ($x=0;$x<2;$x++)
  {
    if ($x>0)
     {
       $x=0;
     }
  }
```